# Same Material, different results?

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I've linked to a [blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yjl2j5wg4eo3wbh/Mat_Tex.blend?dl=0) containing bits of two objects, both with a green material, and both (at least as far as I can tell) with the same texture. In fact the object on the left (named "water") was created from the object on the right (named "terrain") after the material was created. They look the same in solid shading. But in textured shading, they look different. The water still shows the green material, but the terrain does not. I obviously did something to the terrain object when I was paying insufficient attention, but I cannot figure out what would cause the same material to look different. Help, please?

FWIW, the rendering agent of choice here is Blender internal.

Comment: That is weird.. But they look the same in the render and in GLSL shading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it. The terrain object has a UV map. This causes the diffuse color to be overridden in multitexture view, as the texture under the UV map is displayed instead. Apparently a blank texture appears as white.

This won't affect the render, but if you want the texture display to be consistent, remove th UV map in *Properties editor > Object Data > UV maps*.